# Display specific product attribute in WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy, email-notifications

I can't manage to add a product attribute to a WooCommerce new order email. I have added the snippet below to email-order-items.php (after // SKU.. part), but nothing happens. Even the titel 'Location:' isn't visible. Any thoughts on this?

```
// Attribute
if ( $item_meta->meta ) {echo '<br/><small>Location: ' . nl2br( $product->get_attribute( 'location' ) ) . '</small>';}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Updated** - Instead of overriding Woocommerce templates, always try first to use available hooks like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'add_download_links_to_thank_you_page', 10, 3 );
function add_download_links_to_thank_you_page( $item_id, $item, $order ) {
    // Set below your product attribute taxonomy (always starts with "pa_")
    $taxonomy = 'pa_location';

    // On email notifications
    if ( ! is_wc_endpoint_url() && $item->is_type('line_item') ) {
        $product    = $item->get_product();
        $label_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;

        if ( $term_names = $product->get_attribute( $taxonomy ) ) {
            echo '<br/><small>' . $label_name . ': ' . nl2br( $term_names ) . '</small>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

You can also use `woocommerce_order_item_meta_end` hook instead.